# Headphones on Linux not working until power cycle

Tags: linux, usb, audio, drivers, corsair

I own a pair of headphones - Corsair HS80. It's a wireless model with a USB dongle. For the most part they work flawlessly on Arch Linux, but right after the system boot they are not detected by any audio utilities, e.g. `pamixer --list-sinks` or `pavucontrol`.

The dongle is visible in `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1b1c:0a6b Corsair
```

After I plug-out and plug-in the dongle it starts to work and `lsusb` becomes more descriptive.

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1b1c:0a6b Corsair CORSAIR HS80 RGB Wireless Gaming Receiver
```

Why is that so?
How can I fix this, so I don't have to physically unplug the dongle?

I was trying to programatically powercycle/reset the state of the device, but these attempts didn't work:

- `echo off > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.2/power/control` - no longer supported
- `echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.2/power/level` - no longer supported
- `echo 1-4.2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` - doesn't help